# Create a report export with different field name for first and last name - e.g. First Name field would export as FirstName

Tags: custom-fields, field-mapping, autocomplete

Need to create an export report where First Name field is shown as FirstName and Last Name field is shown as Last Name.

Is there a simple way to rename the Field Name as part of the Export process?   Or perhaps create a Custom Field (e.g. FirstName) that can be automatically filled with the value for "First Name"?

Answer (score 2):

If it is about changing the column header, you can use searchkit,

1. Display the results as a Table
2. Include all the fields as the column you want in the exported file.
3. Rename the column name as per your needs.
4. Refresh the results >> Action >> Download Spreadsheet.

HTH

Pradeep

Comment: thanks, will give that a try

Comment: It worked, thanks for the help.  Now I need to get up to speed on using Search Kit!

Comment: Are you happy to mark the post as answered?